# Pagination querying data from PostgreSQL DB

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, express, sequelize-typescript

I have pagination querying data from PostgreSQL database. Every request i fetch data like this:

```
let lastNArticles: Article[] = await Article.findAll({
                limit: +req.body.count * +req.body.page,
                order: [["created_at", "DESC"]],
                include: [
                    User,
                    {
                        model: ArticleOwnTags,
                        include: [ArticleTag],
                    },
                ],
            });
```

And take from that last "req.body.count" fetched rows. Is there any approaches to fetch only page-size rows count (+req.body.count - page size) not all (count * page) rows? Configuring PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

I found limit offest PostgreSQL. With sequelize it will be like that:

```
let lastNArticles: Article[] = await Article.findAll({
                limit: +req.body.count,
                offset: +req.body.count * +req.body.page
                order: [["created_at", "DESC"]],
                include: [
                    User,
                    {
                        model: ArticleOwnTags,
                        include: [ArticleTag],
                    },
                ],
            });
```